# Подсветка смешанного кода в материалах, публикуемых через админку

Tags: php, wordpress, html, css, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть ли решение, позволяющее обрамлять участок кода на нескольких языках и подсвечивать его. Попробовал несколько плагинов - ни один не помог.

Заметил также, что wordpress сходит с ума, если теги

```
<?php /* random code*/ ?>
```

встречается в тексте.

Единственный плагин, который более-менее справляется, но не подсвечивает как надо - WP-Syntax.
В нём есть возможность указания языка в атрибутах тега, например

```
<pre lang="php">
```

Но, во-первых, при вставке кода приходится вставлять очень много этих pre-тегов, можно и запутаться, а во-вторых, он каждый из тегов отделяет от остального кода, и выходит очень рваное непонятное отображение.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Я [на своем сайте](http://site-style.by) использую плагин [Crayon Syntax Highlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/)
Мне он очень нравится и он очень удобен